# Why am I getting the drop-down value as `undefined' on console.log?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-driven

This is an html snippet of my select tag

```
<select id="selDataset"></select>
```

I've added options and their corresponding values with the following script and have verified them to be there using the inspect tool

```
function addOptions() {
    d3.json(url).then(function(data) {
        data.names.forEach((name, i) => {
            var appendOption = selectDropdown.append("option").text(name).attr('value', i)
        })
        selectDropdown.selectedIndex = 0
    })
}
```

Now I am trying to get value of drop-down!

```
console.log(selectDropdown.value)
```

and I'm getting `undefined` on console, does anyone know why that might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`selectDropdown` is a d3.js `Selection` object, not an `HTMLElement`. You can get the element with `selectDropdown.node()`. `selectDropdown.node().value` is how you get the select element's value.